# How Can I Send Files to Google's Gemini Models via API Call?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-generativeai, google-gemini

## Overview

Currently, I use the GoogleGenerativeAI library to handle generative AI prompt generation requests in my application. Gemini promises to be a multi-modal AI model, and I'd like to enable my users to send files (e.g. PDFs, images, .xls files) in line with their AI prompts.

I was using the following workflow to enable people to upload a file and use it in a prompt:

- Enable file selection from their local machine (e.g. PDFs, .doc, .xls formatted files).
- Upload the file to Google Cloud Storage, get an accessible link to the newly-uploaded file.
- Send the request to Gemini with the link to the file included in the prompt (where appropriate).

However, now I'm finding that this solution doesn't work as it was. Instead, I'm seeing responses like this:

> I lack the ability to access external websites or specific files from
> given URLs, including the one you provided from Google Cloud Storage.
> Therefore, I'm unable to summarize the content of the file.

### What I've Considered

- Using multiple libraries to handle document types client-side to convert them into text (e.g. `pdf-parser` for PDFs) and using [Gemini's image-handling model](https://ai.google.dev/docs/gemini_api_overview#web) when there's an image involved. However, this involves lots of libraries, and it seems that Gemini is promising to handle this for me / my users.
- Pre-processing the uploaded files server-side (for example, sending them to Google's [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai?hl=en)), turning their document into some type of consistently-structured data, then using that data with the GoogleGenerativeAI library. Document AI calls are expensive though and it seems that Gemini is meant to handle this kind of thing.

### My App's Stack (In Case it Matters)

- Firebase / Google Cloud Functions
- Vercel
- Next.js

Can you help with an approach that will enable the user to include files in their requests made (via the web) to Gemini?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to send the image in b64 encoded format?

Comment: No, when we initially used this library, we were able to use the links inline with the prompt, but we can’t do that anymore. So, I’m developing this approach. Do you think this would work for all the different file types?

Comment: Yes, a standard way to submit images to an API is a b64 encoded. It's the case for several API on Google Cloud when the native connection with GCS is not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

> Gemini promises to be a multi-modal AI model

The multi-modal capabilities of Gemini are currently limited, and they are slightly different if you are using the Google AI Studio version of the library or the Google Cloud Vertex AI version of the library.

- The Google AI Studio version only supports text and images that are jpeg, png, hiec, heif, or webp images. These can only be inline. See https://ai.google.dev/api/rest/v1/Content#part
- The Google Cloud Vertex AI version also supports these, but has a couple of additions:

  - URL references to documents in Google Cloud Storage are allowed
  - While inline data is still permitted, you're only allowed one inline image
  - Only png and jpeg image files are supported
  - Video files (mov, mpeg, mp4, mpg, avi, wmv, mpegps, and flv) up to two minutes in length are supported
  - See the field definitions at https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/model-reference/gemini#request_body for more details

Currently, neither library supports other modalities, including PDFs, doc files, spreadsheets, etc. While these may be available in the future, they're not available today.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [generating text from text-and-image input (multimodal)](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/web_quickstart#generate-text-from-text-and-image-input) has an example of how to include image data in a request.

As Guillaume commented, this requires that you include your image data as a base64 encoded *part* in your request. While I didn't test the JavaScript bindings myself yet, this matches with my experience of using Dart bindings - where I also included the images as base64 encoded parts.

Comment: I read through those docs, but they're in reference to an image. For most business use cases (my users), they're using common file formats found in business use cases: PDFs, doc/docx, xls, csv. I wouldn't use the vision model for these file formats, right?

Comment: For other document based formats, I'd first try to upload them and see what happens. If the model doesn't process them as is, generate a screenshot and upload those.

Comment: That seems like an okay workaround, but ultimately professionals are expecting to upload multi-page documents, spreadsheets, etc. Capturing screenshots of something like a spreadsheet could get pretty hairy.

Comment: I just tried passing a PDF and a few queries to the geminiProVision model and got no responses. When I preprocessed the PDF (extracting the first few pages as png), I could ask the model reasonable questions about it. I'm not saying this is an ideal model, but it's what I can do with Gemini today. We can expect all we want, yet have to work with the APIs we're given (or find an API that matches our expectation).

Comment: As an example of the latter: I'm testing the same PDF with ChatGPT 4 too, which *does* handle the file type. Not sure if their API handles it too though.